# How to delete a ref in an array of ref's?

Tags: reactjs

So, I have a dynamic list, where one can add and delete the list via add/delete option given.
So, get the data from the dynamic I am using ref, but the issue arises when I delete an item from that list.

What happens is that the list deleting method is working properly but, the ref's arent getting deleted(which I thought would happen automatically as adding is happening)
defined ref array in constructor:

```
this.refsArrayEnglish = [];
```

Following is my code:

```
{this.props.listOfOptions &&
          this.props.listOfOptions.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                <Form.Group as={Row} style={{ marginTop: "2em" }}>
                  <Form.Label column sm="2" style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}>
                    {item.name}
                  </Form.Label>
                  <Col sm="2">
                    <Form.Control
                      style={{ borderRadius: "0", background: "#f9f9f9" }}
                      type="number"
                      value={item.weightage}
                      onChange={this.props.handleOptionWeightageChange.bind(
                        this,
                        index
                      )}
                      placeholder="weightage"
                    />
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Button
                      style={{ float: "right", color: "grey" }}
                      variant="link"
                      onClick={this.props.deleteOption.bind(this, index)}
                    >
                      X Delete
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                  {/* )} */}
                </Form.Group>
                <div style={{ margin: "0.5em 0" }}>
                  <CKEditor
                    ref={ref => {
                      // Callback refs are preferable when
                      // dealing with dynamic refs

                      this.props.refsArrayEnglish[index] = ref;
                      return true;
                    }}
                    onBeforeLoad={CKEDITOR => {
                      CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
                    }}
                    config={{
                      height: 100
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          })}
```

Now the delete function:

```
deleteOption = index => {
    let currentArrayOfOption = this.state.listOfOptions;
    let letterchartcode = 65;
    currentArrayOfOption.splice(index, 1);
    currentArrayOfOption = currentArrayOfOption.map(item => {
      let name = "Option " + String.fromCharCode(letterchartcode);
      letterchartcode++;
      return { name: name, content: item.content, weightage: item.weightage };
    });

    this.setState(
      {
        listOfOptions: currentArrayOfOption,
        letterchartcode: letterchartcode
      }
    );
  }
```

mock:
[image: mock]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reset the array within `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Tried this: componentDidUpdate() {
    
    this.refsArrayEnglish = [];
  }